# Get text to move with nodes in D3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have code below that procodes a graph similar to [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558). I would like to add labels to the node and hopefully the edges of this graph, however, in my code below, my text on the nodes does not move when the graph is moved. How can I get my text to move with the nodes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
  fill: #f00;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");
    text = svg.selectAll(".text");

var graph = {
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410, "label": "A"},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364, "label": "B"},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365, "label": "C"},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314, "label": "D"},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248, "label": "E"},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207, "label": "F"},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155, "label": "G"},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196, "label": "H"},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148, "label": "I"},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222, "label": "J"},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235, "label": "K"},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185, "label": "L"},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200, "label": "M"}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
};

(function() {
  console.log(graph)
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);

  var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
           .data(force.nodes())
           .enter().append("svg:g");

  text.append("svg:text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.label; })

  text.attr("transform",  function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
      })

})();


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `node` refer to a group of elements, namely the `circle` and the `text` element:

```
node = node.data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .call(drag);

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 12);

node.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dx", -6)
  .attr("dy", 6)
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Then, you need to update the `tick` function, such that it transforms the group instead of the circle only:

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

Finally, a small update to the CSS is required, to reflect the fact that circles are now in a group of class `node`, instead of being of that class themselves:

```
.node circle {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed circle {
  fill: #f00;
}
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6scpa/).

Answer (score 0):

You should translate the `text` groups on the `tick` function, or better yet, append the circles and the text to the groups and translate only the groups in the `tick` function.